Prompt lifecycle management in AWS Bedrock Prompt Management
I could not find a way how I can do prompt lifecycle management in bedrock prompt management. I want a similar feature like how we manage code in github. We create a develop branch, once the development is ready, we create a pull request and merge the code to production branch. I have not been able to find this feature in prompt management
